# Question about inequality of two sets in set theoretic sense

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Suppose we have two sets $A$ and $B$ such that $A\neq B$. What we can say about inclusions between $A$ and $B$?

I came up with the following 4 cases: $A \subsetneq B$, $B \subsetneq A$, $A\nsubseteq B$ and $B \nsubseteq A$.

But I do know how to show it rigorously.

We know that $A=B$ iff $A\subseteq B$ and $B\subseteq A$. Taking contrapositive of this we will get just this: $A\neq B$ iff $A \nsubseteq B$ or $B \nsubseteq A$.

How to get also two more cases? I would be very grateful if anybody can explain it please!

Comment: Not very clear… $A = B \text { iff } (A \subseteq B \text { and } B \subseteq A)$. You have correctly negated the formula and thus what we have is : $\lnot (A \subseteq B) \text { or } \lnot (B \subseteq A)$. Thus, we have only two cases : either $A$ is not a subset of $B$ or $B$ is not a subset of $A$.

Answer (score 1):

$A\not\subseteq B$ or $B\not\subseteq A$ is true if one of the following is true:

- $A\not\subseteq B$ and $B\subseteq A$
- $A\subseteq B$ and $B\not\subseteq A$
- $A\not\subseteq B$ and $B\not\subseteq A$

The first implies $A\neq B$ and $B\subseteq A$, thus $B\subsetneq A$. A similar thing is implied by the second.